# Terraform plan for azure failing in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, jenkins-groovy, terraform-provider-azure

Below is the Jenkins DSL groovy for setting the Terraform path and retrieving the service principal credentials to run Terraform init and Terraform plan.

When ran against Terraform 12.0 version I get the error below even though I tested using the same Azure service principal credentials mentioned in the pipeline as below using a Jenkins free style job and `az login` worked fine.

```
+ terraform init -input=false
[0m[1mInitializing modules...[0m

[0m[1mInitializing the backend...[0m
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError building ARM Config: Error populating Client ID from the Azure CLI: No Authorization Tokens were found - please re-authenticate using `az login`.[0m

[0m[0m[0m


    pipeline{
      agent any
      stages{
        stage('Set Terraform path') {
          steps {
            script {
              def tfHome = tool name: 'Terraform'
              env.PATH = "${tfHome}:${env.PATH}"
            }
            sh 'terraform version'

          }
        }

        stage('Provision infrastructure') {
            steps {
              dir('environments/dev')
              {
                  withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('xx-xxx-subscription-azure-sp')]) {
                        sh 'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -t $AZURE_TENANT_ID'
                        sh 'terraform init -input=false'
                        sh 'terraform plan -out=tfplan -input=false'
                }
                    // sh ‘terraform destroy -auto-approve’
              }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see any errors from the az login? did you follow this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/auth/azure_cli.html

Comment: surprisingly az login works fine. The problem arises only after adding backend.tf config to maintain the Terraform state file. Not sure if the Terraform backend needs a different way of authentication to store the credentials for the storage account and the container where the tfstate file is stored.

Comment: k, admittedly i didnt deal with tf state configs, so dont really know whats going on there, sorry